# Changing the value of a variable after an event

Tags: javascript, variables, object, scope, onchange

Right now in the below code the `var selected` doesn't change (it outputs the empty string i guess). I need you to help me change the selected variable so that the value  should be the selected option all of the time (in the select element). I also want to be able to use that updated variable later in the code outside of the `isSelected` function.

```
var isSelected =  (function(){
  var selected = "";

    return {
        add : function(){
            $("select").on("change", function(){
                selected = $(this).val()
            })
        },
        output : function(){
            alert(selected)
        }
    }
})()

$("select").on("change", function(){
    isSelected.add();
    isSelected.output();
})
```

Thanks im trying my best to learn programing

Comment: Does the `add` method fire, though?

Comment: I don't know all i get is a blank alert box when i change options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var isSelected =  (function(){
  var selected = "";

    return {
        add : function(el){
            selected = $(el).val();
            
        },
        output : function(){
            alert(selected)
        }
    }
})()

$("select").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    isSelected.add(this);
    isSelected.output();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="">Select combo</option>
<option value="Value1">Text1</option>
<option value="Value2">Text2</option>
<option value="Value3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

Use `this` keyword to get current object. Please check the solution, hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is binding to the change event in the `add()` function. You've already captured the change event, so when `add()` runs, it adds another change handler, which won't be triggered until the next change event fires.

The solution is to pass the selected value to `add()` as an argument.

> I also want to be able to use that updated variable later in the code

Simply add another function, something like `getSelected()` which returns the value.

```js
var isSelected =  (function(){
  var selected = "";

    return {
        add : function(value){
            selected = value;
        },
        output : function(){
            alert(selected);
        },
        getSelected : function(){
            return selected;  
        }
    }
})();

$("select").on("change", function(){
    isSelected.add(this.value);
    isSelected.output();
  
    var selected = isSelected.getSelected();
    console.log(selected);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```